# Error in Camunda 8 self-managed Zeebe cluster on AKS: "Context ancestry chain length is abnormally long. This suggests an error in application code."

Tags: java, spring-boot, azure-aks, camunda, zeebe

We have set up Zeebe and Elasticsearch with the official Helm chart “camunda-platform” 8.2.6 on Azure AKS, and we sporadically get following error:

```
message: Context ancestry chain length is abnormally long. This suggests an error in application code. Length exceeded: 1000
logger_name: io.grpc.Context
thread_name: pool-8-thread-1
stack_trace: java.lang.Exception: null
    at io.grpc.Context.validateGeneration(Context.java:1124)
    at io.grpc.Context.<init>(Context.java:202)
    at io.grpc.Context.withValue(Context.java:345)
    at io.opentelemetry.javaagent.shaded.instrumentation.grpc.v1_6.internal.ContextStorageBridge.doAttach(ContextStorageBridge.java:67)
    at io.grpc.Context.attach(Context.java:427)
    at io.grpc.internal.ManagedChannelImpl$ChannelStreamProvider$1RetryStream.newSubstream(ManagedChannelImpl.java:591)
    at io.grpc.internal.RetriableStream.createSubstream(RetriableStream.java:237)
    at io.grpc.internal.RetriableStream.start(RetriableStream.java:369)
    at io.grpc.internal.ClientCallImpl.startInternal(ClientCallImpl.java:289)
    at io.grpc.internal.ClientCallImpl.start(ClientCallImpl.java:191)
    at io.grpc.stub.ClientCalls.startCall(ClientCalls.java:341)
    at io.grpc.stub.ClientCalls.asyncUnaryRequestCall(ClientCalls.java:315)
    at io.grpc.stub.ClientCalls.asyncUnaryRequestCall(ClientCalls.java:303)
    at io.grpc.stub.ClientCalls.asyncServerStreamingCall(ClientCalls.java:89)
    at io.camunda.zeebe.gateway.protocol.GatewayGrpc$GatewayStub.activateJobs(GatewayGrpc.java:912)
    at io.camunda.zeebe.client.impl.worker.JobPoller.poll(JobPoller.java:103)
    at io.camunda.zeebe.client.impl.worker.JobPoller.poll(JobPoller.java:92)
    at io.camunda.zeebe.client.impl.worker.JobWorkerImpl.poll(JobWorkerImpl.java:172)
    at io.camunda.zeebe.client.impl.worker.JobWorkerImpl.lambda$tryPoll$0(JobWorkerImpl.java:141)
    at java.base/java.util.Optional.ifPresent(Optional.java:178)
    at io.camunda.zeebe.client.impl.worker.JobWorkerImpl.tryPoll(JobWorkerImpl.java:138)
    at io.camunda.zeebe.client.impl.worker.JobWorkerImpl.onScheduledPoll(JobWorkerImpl.java:128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:539)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:304)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1136)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:635)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
```

We use following configuration for the Helm chart:

```
global:
  elasticsearch:
    host: infra-camunda-elasticsearch
    port: 9200
  identity:
    auth:
      enabled: false
  ingress:
    enabled: false
  zeebePort: 26500
connectors:
  enabled: false
elasticsearch:
  enabled: true
  clusterName: infra-camunda
  nodeGroup: elasticsearch
  masterService: infra-camunda-elasticsearch
  nodeAffinity:
    requiredDuringSchedulingIgnoredDuringExecution:
      nodeSelectorTerms:
        - matchExpressions:
            - key: nodepool
              operator: In
              values:
                - default
  priorityClassName: infra-base
  replicas: 2
  resources:
    requests:
      cpu: 500m
  esConfig:
    elasticsearch.yml: |
      ingest.geoip.downloader.enabled: false
identity:
  enabled: false
operate:
  enabled: false
optimize:
  enabled: false
postgresql:
  enabled: false
prometheusServiceMonitor:
  enabled: false
tasklist:
  enabled: false
zeebe:
  clusterSize: 3
  partitionCount: 3
  replicationFactor: 3
  logLevel: INFO
  affinity:
    nodeAffinity:
      requiredDuringSchedulingIgnoredDuringExecution:
        nodeSelectorTerms:
          - matchExpressions:
              - key: nodepool
                operator: In
                values:
                  - default
  priorityClassName: infra-base
  env:
    - name: ZEEBE_BROKER_CLUSTER_MEMBERSHIP_PROBETIMEOUT
      value: 500ms
zeebe-gateway:
  replicas: 2
  podLabels:
    component: infra-camunda-zeebe-gateway
  logLevel: INFO
  affinity:
    nodeAffinity:
      requiredDuringSchedulingIgnoredDuringExecution:
        nodeSelectorTerms:
          - matchExpressions:
              - key: nodepool
                operator: In
                values:
                  - default
  priorityClassName: infra-base
  env:
    - name: ZEEBE_GATEWAY_CLUSTER_MEMBERSHIP_PROBETIMEOUT
      value: 500ms
```

As for the client we use Spring Zeebe 8.2.0 in a Spring Boot 3.0.6 application

```
      <dependency>
        <groupId>io.camunda</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-zeebe-starter</artifactId>
        <version>8.2.0</version>
      </dependency>
```

with following configuration

```
zeebe:
  client:
    broker:
      gateway-address: infra-zeebe:26500
    security:
      plaintext: true
    worker:
      max-jobs-active: 32
      threads: 1
```

Our original setup was different from the proposed installation in the Camunda Platform 8 installation, so we set it now up using the Helm chart provided by Camunda.
We temporarily disabled the network policies in our AKS cluster to avoid problems related to blocked connections.
Sometimes it seems as if the Zeebe clients would just keep working, but sometimes we have to restart them to get them processing again.
Unfortunately the error message is to generic to really yield some insights to me and I cannot find anything related to this error and Zeebe online. So has anyone encountered the same problem in a cloud cluster setting?